# SAPui5 sap.viz.ui5.StackedColumn custom tooltip on data point

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to implement a custom tooltip in a sap viz stacked column chart. This is the small popup window that appears when the mouse hovers a datapoint. My problem is how to detect the position of the data point so that the tooltip popup points to it. Currently it always points to the graph itself, not the datapoint inside the graph.
Here's what I have:

```
graph = new sap.viz.ui5.StackedColumn({
      width: graphWidth,
      height : graphHeight,
      //.. more properties here
      interaction: new sap.viz.ui5.types.controller.Interaction({
          decorations: [{name: "showDetail", fn: showDetailHandler}, {name: "hideDetail", fn:hideDetailHandler}]
      }),
```

and the showDetailHandler is currently like this. It is supposed to display a popup pointing to the data point.

```
var showDetailHandler = function(oEvent){
        var data = oEvent.data;
      var offset = '0 0';
      var tp3 = new sap.ui.ux3.ToolPopup({
            content : [ new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                text : "button"
            }) ],
      });
      offset = '0 0';
      offset = oEvent.position.x + " " + oEvent.position.y;
      tp3.setPosition(  sap.ui.core.Popup.Dock.CenterBottom, 
                        sap.ui.core.Popup.Dock.CenterTop, 
                        $(oEvent.container),
                        offset,
                        "none");
      if (tp3.isOpen()) {
          tp3.close();
      } else {
          tp3.open(sap.ui.core.Popup.Dock.CenterBottom, sap.ui.core.Popup.Dock.CenterTop);
      }
    };
```

The docs around this are here:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Popup.html#setPosition
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.viz.ui5.types.controller.Interaction.html#getDecorations

My understanding is that the offset is an offset to the point calculated by the anchor point. Problem is, offset is completely ignored. Popup always appears at the top of the graph.

However, the normal tooltip appears in the correct place.

Any idea/example?

Thank you in advance.